# How to add upload image metabox in wordpress and use it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add an upload image metabox in my custom post type to upload image using that and get the link of that image and use it in my single.php page.
I know I have to do it in functions.php but I dont know what to di in `wp_nonce_field` and how to get the image and save it.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256043/how-to-add-meta-box-for-image-upload-using-wordpress-media-uploader

Comment: I checked it and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use Advanced Custom Fields Plugin. It will give you option to add meta box of any type you want, image type included.

After creating meta group create a meta box of image type and associate it with your required Custom Post Type.

It also has option to return image ID or URL after the image is uploaded.

Checkout below URLs,

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

[ACF Image Type Meta Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/)

Hope this one hrlps :)